Kotlin Android SQLite INSERT INTO query increment row count, but values are not inserting
I am trying to insert a row of values in to SQLite database. The row count value return from insertorThrow function is higher than -1 and its incrementing each time. There is no error from SQLite exception but when I check inside the table, its empty.
Below is the create table query
  database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ReaderFlag ("
            + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"
            + "reader_customer_id INTEGER NOT NULL,"
            + "reader_route_id INTEGER NOT NULL,"
            + "start_end_flag TEXT NOT NULL);");

Below is the function and Insert query
    fun uploadFlagToCustomer(
    database: SQLiteDatabase,
    flags: List<StartStopPremisesFlag>
) {
    flags.forEach { action ->
        //val action = flags.get(0)
        var flagString = ""
        if (action.start) {// converting boolean to string
            flagString = "start"
        }
        if (action.stop) {// converting boolean to string
            flagString = "stop"
        }

      /*  val contentValue = ContentValues()
        contentValue.put(ReaderTable.startEndFlag, flagString)
        contentValue.put(ReaderTable.customerID, action.customer)
        contentValue.put(ReaderTable.routeID, action.route)
        contentValue.put(ReaderTable.customer_address, action.address.trim())*/
        val address = "\"${action.address.trim()}\""
        val flagUnit = "\"${flagString}\""
        System.out.println("flagvalue $flagString, ${action.customer}, ${action.route}, ${action.address}")
        val query = "INSERT INTO $Reader_Table (${ReaderTable.customerID}, ${ReaderTable.routeID}, ${ReaderTable.startEndFlag}) VALUES (${action.customer}, ${action.route}, $flagUnit)"
        val error = database.execSQL(query)
        System.out.println("errorinsert1: $error, $query")
        /*  try {
              val error:Long = database.insertOrThrow(
                  Reader_Table,
                  null,
                  contentValue
              )
              System.out.println("errorinsert1: $error")
          }catch (e: SQLiteException){
              System.out.println("errorinsert2: $e")
          }catch (er: SQLiteAbortException){
              System.out.println("errorinsert3: $er")
          }*/
    }
}

Below is the data class
data class StartStopPremisesFlag(
val customer: Int,
val route: Int,
val address: String,
var start: Boolean,
var stop: Boolean)

Please help, Couldn't find what is missing.

If the row count increased, the data was inserted.  Explain why you think it wasn't, and what you were doing to try to find it

In my case I agree that row count is increasing without any error. When I check the SQLite database using a DB Browser, there is no data in the table.

Are you 100% sure the database file your program is using is the same one you're looking at in an external tool?

Yes, 100% sure, I have checked it through the Android App Inspector as well

I found the issue, It was simple, the uploadFlagToCustomer() function is inside a ViewModel and I am calling this function from an AlertDialog.Builder. when I removed that AlertDialog, its inserting value to SQLite.
Below is the code on the Activity
    private fun callDialog(database, flags) {
    flagViewModel.uploadFlagToCustomer(database, flags)
 /*   val bl = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    bl.setTitle("Save/Clear Flags?")
    bl.setNeutralButton("Clear", null)
    bl.setPositiveButton(
        "Save & Exit"
    ) { dialog: DialogInterface?, _: Int -> flagViewModel.uploadFlagToCustomer(database, flags) }
    val d: Dialog = bl.create()
    d.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
    d.setCancelable(false)
    d.setOnDismissListener { _: DialogInterface? ->
        flagViewModel.clearFlags(routeId)
    }
    d.show()*/
}

There was no issue with the SQlite it was this part that caused the problem
